# Selenium wont open URL when i'm in chrome profile

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

There is a problem that it just opens the standart start page and isn't reacting to browser.get() line.
When i'm using it without profile it works just fine.

I need my profile to be opened too

Here is code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import os

opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opt.binary_location = r'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe'    
chromedriver_exe_location = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'chromedriver.exe')  
profile_path = r'C:\\Users\\rektl\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data' 
opt.add_argument('--user-data-dir={}'.format(profile_path))
opt.add_argument('--profile-directory={}'.format('Profile 2')) 
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_exe_location, options=opt, service_args='')
browser.get("https:\\youtube.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

### Issue

Using chrome data, you can only have **one instance of a chrome browser** open at once. I am guessing that you have an additional browser open.

### Solution

If you have no purpose of logging into the site, then **I do not recommend using chrome data**. You can also shorten your code to just these two lines. There are *no passed parameters* since you now have no chrome options and your *chrome driver is already in your cwd*:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https:\\youtube.com")
```

Comment: Reason why i have a lot of lines - i need it to open dedicated chrome profile and i have purpose to make autobot. And i need to have one chrome tab opened so i can skip logging in thingie(Site is made like that, so opened tab with that site is ordinary thing).

Comment: Okay so you are logging in... then use Chrome data how you were using it but close the other tab as it is not necessary